# Python error message "kernel does not exist"

Tags: python

I installed a package `xsequence` in python, but when I tried to run this code

```
import at
import xsequence

from xsequence.lattice import Lattice
from xsequence.conversion_utils import conv_utils
import xsequence.elements_dataclasses as xed
```

I got the attached error massage.

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Comment: Try restarting the IDE or whatever you are running the code

Comment: @raspiduino I restarted my PC and i still see the error, i can run other python code but the error happens with this code only

Comment: I don't think that library is even finished. The product is in version 0.0.1 and there's not even a description of what it is for

Comment: @HuLuViCa I am not sure if i understood it well could you please clarify more?

Comment: @ely66 The package, https://pypi.org/project/xsequence/ has no description and is still on version 0.0.1. HuLu is saying that the package is not finished, and shouldn't be used. It seems like it's still in development.

Comment: I would also ask: why are you using it? How do you know what it is for?

Comment: What are you using to run it? Please [edit] to add details, otherwise we can only guess. That error message is definitely not from Python itself, since it doesn't have a kernel. It looks like you might be using an IPython frontend.

Comment: I would guess Pycharm, it looks similar to my Pycharm installation.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue and I had looked through some places and I don’t remember the reference but I did the following
Uninstall Jupyter notebook and along with its dependencies :

```bash
pip3 uninstall jupyter
pip3 uninstall jupyter_core
pip3 uninstall jupyter-client
pip3 uninstall jupyter-console
pip3 uninstall notebook
pip uninstall ipykernel
pip uninstall jupyterlab-server
pip uninstall jupyterlab
```

Once all the dependencies are uninstalled, delete anaconda and install it again

It resolved my error!

Comment: This does not appear to be a Jupyter based error.  Nor does the IDE look like Jupyter.

Comment: Same with Conda-based environment, basically removal of the directory and reinstallation solves the issue:

`rm -rf /path/to/env; mamba env update -p /path/to/env jupyterlab`

As demonstrated also at https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5814